# JavaFX - avoiding a retracing of common hexagon edges in a hexagonal map

Tags: javafx

```
private void addHexagonsToScreen() {
    for(Hex hex : map.getMap()) {
        Point[] corners = screen.polygonCorners(hex);
        int i = 0;
        Double[] points = new Double[12];
        for(Point point : corners) {
            points[i] = point.getX();
            points[i+1] = point.getY();
            i += 2;
        }
        this.root.getChildren().add(drawHexagon(points));
    }
}

private Polygon drawHexagon(Double[] points) {

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.getPoints().addAll(points);
    polygon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    polygon.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return polygon;
}
```

This is how I define a `point`.

```
public class Point {

private final double x, y;

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/**
 * @return the screen x-coordinate.
 */
public double getX() {
    return x;
}

/**
 * @return the screen y-coordinate.
 */
public double getY() {
    return y;
} }
```

[image: Hex Map]

This is currently how I am drawing my hexagons on a `Pane` object. As you can see in the picture below, I'm fairly certain that most of the lines are actually being retraced because each edge (except the outer edges) are obviously common to two hexagons. In order to solve this, I instead calculated all the points at once then passed that into the `Polygon()` function as a `double []` with the intention of drawing just one polygon rather than many.

```
private void addHexagonsToScreen() {
    int i = 0;
    Double[] points = new Double[map.getMap().size() * 12];
    for(Hex hex : map.getMap()) {
        Point[] corners = screen.polygonCorners(hex);
        for(Point point : corners) {
            points[i] = point.getX();
            points[i+1] = point.getY();
            i += 2;
        }           
    }
    this.root.getChildren().add(drawHexagon(points));
}
```

This resulted in the second picture. I think the solution requires that I specify "only connect each point to its closest other point", but I am unsure of how to do this. Is there a simple solution to my problem?

[image: Hex Map 2]

The reason the hex map is off in the top left corner is because I'm specifying the origin of my hex map to be 0,0 and calculating a pixel location as such. Obviously I have done something wrong in converting my 0,0 hexagon location to correspond with the center of the `Pane` and growing Y+ in the up direction and X+ in the right direction.

Comment: I edited your link to the first image so that it worked. There is no link to a second image: please [edit] the question and include that. You probably need to include more code (instead of just describing it): especially the attempt to use a single `Polygon`.

Comment: Where is your `drawHexagon()` method?

Comment: I have added it. I apologize for not putting it in the first place, I didn't want to just copy my whole class up here but I will if you need it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you draw the lines yourself.

Comment: I would also add the points if I were you.

Comment: One strategy that I can imagine working would be to use a `Path` and generate `PathElement`s as either `LineTo` (if it hasn't been drawn before`) or `MoveTo` (if it has). There's probably some nice known (though not by me) algorithms for this...

Comment: Added Point class. If anyone is interested in my entire code, i am happy to just post the git link.

Comment: You can just use the standard `Point2D` class instead of your `Point`, btw. I guess the real question here is: what are the constraints? Do you want/need each hexagon represented by a separate object? Is it enough just to make this from lines? What do you really need here?

Comment: Yea i figured there is a lot I am writing that is redundant (i.e. Point), but I enjoy writing everything from scratch that I possibly can, helps me learn. In regards to your second question, now that I think about it, I suppose I do need each hexagon to be its own node as I will want to color each of them differently, possibly animate them, allow easy interactions with the mouse.I just wish there was a way to avoid retracing lines where nodes intersect.

Comment: So maybe represent each as a `Group`. The `Group` contains a `Polygon` with fill but no `Stroke` (so you can easily change the color, etc), and three `Line`s (the east, southeast, and southwest) edges, if that makes sense. If it's in the top row, it additionally contains `Line`s for the northeast and northwest edges, and if it's the leftmost hexagon in its row, it also contains a `Line` for the west edge. You can add mouse listeners directly to the `Group`, animate the `Group` (though that may need adding the "missing" edges), etc.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I’ll look into that suggestion. I understand what you mean conceptually.